# Constants in Padrino/Sinatra routes

Tags: ruby, sinatra, padrino

In Sinatra/Padrino where is a sensible place to add constants for use inside routes?

I'm using Padrino to mount multiple apps so I want the constants available to all apps. (All apps inherit from a base class.)

I've used [Sinatra.helpers](http://www.sinatrarb.com/extensions.html#extending_the_request_context_with_) to add methods for use inside routes.

I was hoping for a similar approach for constants.

**Update**

This appears to be a scoping issue, but I can't figure out what's wrong in this scenario.

Here is a stripped down padrino app which demonstrates the problem:

*app.rb*

```
class MyProject < Padrino::Application
  register Padrino::Rendering
  register Padrino::Mailer
  register Padrino::Helpers

  MY_CONST = 123
end
```

*controllers.rb*

```
MyProject.controller do
  get "/" do
    p self.class            # => MyProject
    p self.class.constants  # => [:DATA_ATTRIBUTES, ... <snip>..., :MY_CONST, ... <snip>... ]
    p MyProject::MY_CONST   # => 123
    p MY_CONST              # => NameError - uninitialized constant MY_CONST
  end
end
```

Comment: you could add a class constant they should be available everywhere just like class vars.

Comment: in the app class? constants added to app classes which extend Padrino::Application are not available inside routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so apparently I'm hitting an issue with how Ruby handles constant lookups within a proc that is instance_evaled.

Here is a Padrino-free way to recreate the error:

```
class Thing

  MY_CONST = 123

  def doStuff (&block)
    p "doStuff: #{self.class}"        # => "doStuff: Thing"
    p "doStuff: #{MY_CONST}"          # => "doStuff: 123"

    instance_eval &block
  end

  def doOtherStuff (&block)
    p "doOtherStuff: #{self.class}"   # => "doOtherStuff: Thing"
    p "doOtherStuff: #{MY_CONST}"     # => "doOtherStuff: 123"

    yield 
  end
end

t = Thing.new

t.doStuff do 
  doOtherStuff do
    p self.class             # => Thing
    p self.class.constants   # => [:MY_CONST]
    p Thing::MY_CONST        # => 123
    p MY_CONST               # => NameError: uninitialized constant MY_CONST
  end
end
```

Related question: [Constant Lookup with instance_eval in Ruby 1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892726/constant-lookup-with-instance-eval-in-ruby-1-9)

Related blog post: http://jfire.io/blog/2011/01/21/making-sense-of-constant-lookup-in-ruby/

So it looks like my options are limited to:

1. Use a global constant
2. Fully specify the constant (eg: Thing::MY_CONST in the example above)
3. Use a method instead

Answer (score 0):

Mmm, maybe I didn't understand but you could use `apps.rb`

```
Padrino.configure do
   set :foo, :bar
end
```

Then you should be able in all your apps to retrieve your var.

Or In boot or apps.rb add some like:

```
MY_CONST = 1
MyConst = 1
```

Comment: OK cool. I can now use "settings.foo" in my route. That's progress :-) I am still hoping that my routes can use constants as if they were local (ie: unscoped). Is that not possible?

Comment: thanks again. I also assumed that adding the constant to app.rb would work fine. but I'm still having problems. I've updated the question with example code. thanks.

Comment: If you want use it in a global env keep it outside class, otherwise look the final part of the `NameError` it will show you `uninitialized constant MY_CONST for ...`